# Element in Tkinter window below existing Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I want to create a program in Python using Tkinter. It creates several types of outputs, which need different inputs each..

To separate different inputs, i use multiple tabs.

Then, there are inputs which are same for all outputs; is it possible to put their Inputs onto the window, unrelated to the tabs?

The window should look a bit like this with the Radio Buttons always visible:
[image]

The python program is:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window)
tabMakeTea = ttk.Frame(tabControl); tabControl.add(tabMakeTea, text = "Make tea")
tabMakeCoffee = ttk.Frame(tabControl); tabControl.add(tabMakeCoffee, text = "Make coffee")

tabControl.pack(expand = 1, fill="both")

window.mainloop()
```

Now i continue with elements within each Frame; next i need things that should be visible no matter if you are in "tea" or "coffee" tab.

First i placed same inputs to multiple Frames, hoping the data will be read from the respective (active) Frame, but Python reads values from one (always the same) inputs.

Next, i tried to place elements to the `window` element so that it is always visible regardless of the Frame, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
Label(window, text = "Sugar: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Right now i have another `Frame` for this kind of inputs, but i find it not very user-friendly.

Could you anybody please advise how to get to the

i tried placing the element straight to the "window" element, which results in error "cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack".

i tried googling "adding element to multiple frames" and "placing element on window bellow Frame element" with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want widgets *outside* of your tab control, you only need to make them children of the root window instead of the tab control

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window)
tabMakeTea = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # this widget is a child of tabControl
tabControl.add(tabMakeTea, text = "Make tea")
tabMakeCoffee = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # this widget is a also child of tabControl
tabControl.add(tabMakeCoffee, text = "Make coffee")
tabControl.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

new_frame = Frame(window)  # this Frame is a child of the root window
new_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
# this example button is a child of 'new_frame', and should appear below 'tabControl'
new_button = ttk.Button(new_frame, text='Hello')
new_button.pack(expand=False, fill='none')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Missing bracket in line 13 `new_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both'`